# Is python zip file module selfmodifying safe?

Tags: python, zip

Is it safe that appending files to running python zip file module itself?

I've written __main__.py as follows.

```
import sys, zipfile
w = zipfile.ZipFile(sys.argv[0], "w") # opening script self for writing.
w.write("newfile")                    # appending "newfile" to script self.
w.close()

r = zipfile.ZipFile(sys.argv[0], "r") # opening script self for reading.
print(r.open("newfile").read())       # print "newfile" content.
r.close()
```

and, executed as follows.

```
$ ls
__main__.py
$ zip -r test.zip *    <<<=== creating python zip file module.
    adding: __main__.py (deflated 35%)
$ echo "ABC" > newfile <<<=== creating a new file to be added to "test.zip"
$ ls
__main__.py  newfile  test.zip
$ python test.zip      <<<=== running "test.zip" python zip file module.
b'ABC\n'               <<<=== printed out "newfile" content.
```

from this result, it looks working well. but, I couldn't confirmed this selfmodying method and behavior result alongs with the python specifications or not.